# parse Json String which could contain a JsonArray or just a JsonObject

Tags: java, json

My Json string could be one of the following two format, I wounder how can I parse them since I don't know if it is a JsonArray or a JsonObject.

```
{"a":{"a":"a","a":"a","a":"a","a":"a"}}

{"a":[{"a":"a","b":"a","a":"a","a":"a"},{"b":"b","b":"b","b":"b","b":"b"}]}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code to give you an idea of parsing a token stream

This is called with the initial token,

nextToken(t) retrieves the next token from the stream.

parseJsonElement is recursive to handle the tree nature.

```
public Object parseJsonElement(Token t){
    if (t.isArrayStart()){
       // is an array so create list and put child elements into list
        List list = new List();
        t = nextToken(t);
        while (!t.isArrayEnd()){
           list.add(parseJsonElement(t));
        }
        return list;
    }else if (t.isObjectStart()){
       // is an object so return parsed object
        return parseJsonElement(t);
    }else // handle something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse your JSON, construct a [JsonParser](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html). The return type for its `parse` methods is [JsonElement](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html). As you can see by reading the class's method list, it has methods to tell you whether it's an Object, Array, or other. You can then either case the object into the appropriate subclass (`JsonObject`, `JsonArray`, whatever) or use the provided convenience methods to do it for you.

From there, you can inspect the object or array and get the properties, elements, primitive values, etc. These will also come out as JsonElement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSONLib or Gson both libraries have an abstract class called JsonElement. That class has the ability to answer you if it is a JsonObject or JsonArray (#isJsonArray() #isJsonObject() methods). Then, you can cast it properly.